# What is the difference between nxtG and nxt 2.0?

Tags: nxt, mindstorms

I'm familiar with NXT 1.0 and 2.0 but I've also seen reference (program samples, etc.) to NXT G. What's the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NXT-G is the graphical programming software that comes with NXT 1.0 [(8527)](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=8527-1) and 2.0 [(8547)](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=8547-1).

[image]

The NXT-G software has been improved for the second version of the set which also comes with a few different bricks (including different tyres) and a different box design.

Answer (score 0):

I seems like NXT-G *is* version 1.0. According to [the Wikipedia article on the Lego Mindstorms NXT:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lego_Mindstorms_NXT#NXT-G)

> NXT-G v1.0 is a graphical programming environment that comes bundled with the NXT.